# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE not picking up all values in a CSV file

Tags: csv, load-data-infile

I'm trying to load a CSV file into MySQL via the command line, but a lot of the values just aren't appearing. Here is my query:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/zachsmith/Dropbox/1_computer_business/2014_MSc/assignments/databases/CSCresults_no_headers.CSV' INTO TABLE Temp FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' (Year, StudentID, Degree, CourseCode, CourseDescrip, Session, Code, Percent, Symbol, Gender, SAstatus, ForeignCountry);
```

and what's added looks like this:

```
mysql> select * from Temp
    -> ;
+------+-----------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------+--------------+------+---------+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
| Year | StudentID | Degree | CourseCode  | CourseDescrip                  | Session      | Code | Percent | Symbol | Gender | SAstatus | ForeignCountry              |
+------+-----------+--------+-------------+--------------------------------+--------------+------+---------+--------+--------+----------+-----------------------------+
                   | EB022  | CSC1015F    | Computer Science 1015          | Semester One | UGRD |      83 | 1      | M      | F        | Tanzania
                   | EB022  | CSC1016S    | Computer Science 1B            | Semester Two | UGRD |      60 | 2-     | M      | F        | Tanzania
                   | SB006  | CSC1010H    | Compass I -CompScAcadAssProg   | Full Year    | UGRD |      48 | SF     | M      | F        | Tanzania
                   | SB006  | CSC1015F    | Computer Science 1015          | Semester One | UGRD |      26 | F      | M      | F        | Tanzania
                      |001  | CSC6000W    | PhD in Computer Science        | Full Year    | DOCT |       0 |        | M      | F        | Sudan
                   | SB006  | CSC1010H    | Compass I -CompScAcadAssProg   | Full Year    | UGRD |      56 | 3      | M      | F        | Tanzania
                   | SB006  | CSC1015F    | Computer Science 1015          | Semester One | UGRD |      41 | F      | M      | F        | Tanzania
                           || CSC1010H    | Compass I -CompScAcadAssProg   | Full Year    | UGRD |      64 | SP     | M      | C        | 
                           || CSC3002F    | Computer Science 302           | Semester One | UGRD |      70 | 2+     | M      | C        | 
                           || CSC3003S    | Computer Science 303           | Semester Two | UGRD |      70 | 2+     | M      | C        | 
                           || CSC3002F    | Comput
```

A lot of stuff is just cut out - like the dates and student ID's (this is dummy data) and even half the degree code in the 5th row...

all the fields are varchar(30) as I am just going to treat everything as a string. Why is this?

I looked on Excel and it picks up everything

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the csv file with a text editor. See to it if the fields are really `TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'` and each column corresponds to the same field in the `Temp` table. Remember that if a CSV field is left with no value in it, it should still be enclosed by double quotes `""`.